# Testing C++ code: Using test libraries

Tags: c++, testing, googletest

I've been studying C++ for a while, but this is the first time I'm into a C++ project (a pet configuration parser library). I'm using the [Google C++ Testing Framework](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/) to test this. But I don't know if I'm doing it right.

Currently, I've ripped off some parts of this Google test library and put it into my projects `Test/googletest` directory. It works OK, but I wonder if this is how I'm supposed to do this. I'm including the source code of the testing framework in my project and it will be released with my code. This makes me feel uncomfortable.

I wandered through [some C++ projects on GitHub](https://github.com/languages/C++/most_watched), trying to see how other people deal with this. Some have custom framework-lets, and most solve the whole problem with not testing the code at all.

I wonder if I'm taking this right, or otherwise how can I adopt a testing method that will both keep the framework out of my source tree and let me release my code with tests buildable and executable by the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning your build, you're doing it right. The gtest readme explicitly states that building gtest (you can pack a libgtest.a from the two object files) along with your project is the prefered way to do it.

Concerning the distribution:
Ideally, you could have your build tool (make, CMake, etc) check out / fetch the required gtest version from its own repository. But I don't think there is much harm if you add an "external" folder to your project and include stuff like gtest in your own repository.

Comment: So, the user that checks out the distribution will need svn installed if (s)he wants to test the build. Is this the general practice in the community?

Comment: i can only speak from my experience. but if you check out a project via svn/git you can be expected to the that particular system installed, can't you? afaik gtest is available on both, svn and git. 
but i am speaking from my experience with a handful of projects and not "general practice in the community" which I don't know to much about

Comment: AFAIK gtest does not have a git repository, but I can maintain my git mirror of their repository. This 'fetch when make tests' approach seems like a nice idea. Thanks!